# EF Core with inheritance and Automapper mapping: how to query and map a SQL view with inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have an old MySQL table that I scaffolded with Entity Framework Core (2.2), using Pomelo.
I had to create an SQL view to list all users simulating an inheritance with a discriminator column.

So I have multiple classes map to one SQL View. The base class is `ViewUser`, and the inherited ones are `ViewUserCollaborator`, `ViewUserClient`, ...

EF Core configuration:

```cs
public DbQuery<ViewUser> ViewUsers { get; set; }

[...]

modelBuilder.Query<ViewUser>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToView("v_users")
        .HasDiscriminator<string>("discriminator")
        .HasValue<ViewUserClient>("Client")
        .HasValue<ViewUserCollaborator>("Collaborator")
        .HasValue<ViewUser>("User");
}
```

Now I have a repository exposing domain entities with the same inheritance but different classes and properties. Base class is `User`, and inherited ones are `Collaborator`, `Client`, ...

I got some AutoMapper configurations:

```cs
CreateMap<ViewUser, User>()
                .Include<ViewUserCollaborator, Collaborator>()
                .Include<ViewUserClient, Client>()
                .ForMember(e => e.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(m => m.UserId))
                ...;

            CreateMap<ViewUserClient, Client>()...;

            CreateMap<ViewUserCollaborator, Collaborator>()...;
```

Using my repository, I would like to query all users retrieving inheritance, based on SQL View.
I call Users and I'll get a list of Users with inheritance ; e.g.: Users.OfType() returns a non-empty list.

I tried to use projection, but the inheritance is not kept.

```cs
return Context.ViewUsers.ProjectTo<User>();
```

I tried to map in the query. It's working but the performance are really poor, because the mapping is done during the query not during the enumeration.

```cs
return from u Context.ViewUsers
       select u.Discriminator == "Collaborator" ? Map<Collaborator>(u) :
              u.Discriminator == "Client" ? Map<Client>(u) :
              Map<User>(u);
```

Tell me if I'm wrong, but I think there are only two possible ways: "project" with inheritance or map during enumeration, but I didn't find how.

And, in order to add some complexity, I need to retrieve other datas only for specific user type (e.g.: join on UserDepartment if the User is Collaborator), but I have some other ways to do that.

My main problem is to get all users with inheritance with one query.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Inheritance doesn't really work with `ProjectTo` because EF6 doesn't support that. Some things might work, but you're stepping on thin ice here. What you can do is fetch all the data you need with `ProjectTo` and then use `Map` to solve the inheritance part in memory.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I do that, I have to project to my base User class. But when I need to map I won't have the specific properties for each child class, because the View is not accessible anymore. Or I need to join the view to get these, but the perf will be awful.

Comment: Rows are not objects. You need to have the db help with your object structure. That's just your everyday ORM problem. All `ProjectTo` does is write an expression for you and pass it to EF. In the end it's all SQL. So clearly you need to solve that before anything else.